# Does flutter web somehow allows to pick file from a fixed path on local machine?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, filepicker

Using flutter web, need to access a local file from PC whose path is fixed.
May be user can set permission once and then it automatically picks the file from that fixed path every time on its own?

Answer (score 0):

This should already be supported out of the box by the [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) plugin, which also works with flutter web?

Comment: But does it allow to hardcode the path to pick the file from and not ask user to pick the file?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. No, I don't think that's possible given the lack of dart:io support.